# Writing dataframe to .txt file in R, without ¬† added

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I have merged two tables together and I want to write them to a `.txt` file. I have managed to do this, however when I open the `.txt` file in excel the symbols `¬†` have been added to some values. How do I stop this from happening? I have used the following code:

```
ICU_PPS <- merge(ICU, PPS, by=c("Study","Lane","Isolate_ID","Sample_Number","MALDI_ID", "WGS","Source"),all=TRUE)
write.table(ICU_PPS,"ICUPPS2.txt", sep="\t", row.names = FALSE)
```

An example of some values in a column that I get:

```
100_1#175
100_1#176
100_1#177
100_1#179
100_1#18¬†
100_1#19¬†
100_1#20¬†
```

What I want to achieve:

```
100_1#175
100_1#176
100_1#177
100_1#179
100_1#18
100_1#19
100_1#20
```

Comment: Do you know whether your column should include any characters other than numbers?

Comment: The column contains those numbers which have hashtags and underscores in as shown in example, but no other characters

Comment: I believe the problem may be due to whitespace after those numbers with fewer digits i.e "100_1#18 " compared to "100_1#179"